# Look up secrets from gcloud secrets manager directly as secretGenerator with kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-secrets, kustomize, google-secret-manager

I am setting up my `Kubernetes` cluster using `kubectl -k` (kustomize). Like any other such arrangement, I depend on some secrets during deployment. The route I want go is to use the `secretGenerator` feature of `kustomize` to fetch my secrets from files or environment variables.

However managing said files or environment variables in a secure and portable manner has shown itself to be a challenge. Especially since I have 3 separate namespaces for test, stage and production, each requiring a different set of secrets.

So I thought surely there must be a way for me to manage the secrets in my cloud provider's official way (google cloud platform - secret manager).

So how would the `secretGenerator` that accesses secrets stored in the secret manager look like?

My naive guess would be something like this:

```
secretGenerator:
 - name: juicy-environment-config
   google-secret-resource-id: projects/133713371337/secrets/juicy-test-secret/versions/1
   type: some-google-specific-type
```

- Is this at all possible?
- What would the example look like?
- Where is this documented?
- **If this is not possible, what are my alternatives?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a plugin for that. The plugin system in Kustomize is somewhat new (added about 6 months ago) so there aren't a ton in the wild so far, and Secrets Manager is only a few weeks old. You can find docs at https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/docs/plugins for writing one though. That links to a few Go plugins for secrets management so you can probably take one of those and rework it to the GCP API.

Comment: wow, I guess I must be a cool kid using such bleeding edge tech without even knowing about it. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

There [is a Go plugin](https://github.com/ForgeCloud/ksecrets) for this (I helped write it), but plugins weren't supported until more recent versions of Kustomize, so you'll need to install Kustomize directly and run it like `kustomize build <path> | kubectl apply -f -` rather than `kubectl -k`. This is a good idea anyway IMO since there are a lot of other useful features in newer versions of Kustomize than the one that's built into kubectl.

As seen in the [examples](https://github.com/ForgeCloud/ksecrets/tree/master/example), after you've installed the plugin (or you can run it within Docker, see readme) you can define files like the following and commit them to version control:

`my-secret.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: crd.forgecloud.com/v1
kind: EncryptedSecret
metadata:
  name: my-secrets
  namespace: default
source: GCP
gcpProjectID: my-gcp-project-id
keys:
- creds.json
- ca.crt
```

In your `kustomization.yaml` you would add

```yaml
generators:
- my-secret.yaml
```

and when you run `kustomize build` it'll automatically retrive your secret values from Google Secret Manager and output Kubernetes `secret` objects.